# Grails with Spring Security Plugin and Salted Passwords

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to do salted password hashing in my Grails + Spring Security application. I have used the tutorials on the Grails site, and also ones I found randomly on the Internet.

At the moment, I have everything set up according to [this](http://blog.swwomm.com/2010/06/grails-passwords-salted.html) tutorial. However I run into a problem when deploying the application with the following bean declaration in `resources.groovy`:

```
saltSource(cq.MySaltSource) {
    userPropertyToUse = CH.config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty
}
```

It complains that it cannot find `CH`.

After digging around, I found a post on [nabble](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-Core-plugin-and-multiple-salt-sources-td3638236.html) stating the following:

> Also - don't use ConfigurationHolder (CH) since it's deprecated in 2.0. You can pass in a reference to the grailsApplication bean and get the config from there:

```
saltSource(MySaltSource) {
  grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
}
```

> and then in your class add

```
def grailsApplication
```

> and get the property via

```
String userPropertyToUse  grailsApplication.config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty
```

The part that I do not follow is the last statement about "...and get the property via...". The line of code he gives there seems malformed to me.

If anyone can shed some light here, or provide a different approach to using salted passwords with Grails and Spring Security, I would appreciate it. Note that it needs to be unique salts per user, not system-wide or a single salt, or a salt derived from `username`.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

So I got it working with the first tutorial (forgot the `import` statement at the top of `resources.groovy`. But I would still like to use the second way (to stay compatible with the future version).

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have written a complete tutorial on this if anyone browsing here is interested:

[Setting up a Grails web application using Spring Security and salted passwords.](https://web.archive.org/web/20161004154656/http://grailsplayground.blogspot.com/2011/10/setting-up-grails-web-application-using.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `resources.groovy` where you're defining the `saltSource` bean the `GrailsApplication` is available as the `application` variable, so you can change the bean declaration to

```
saltSource(cq.MySaltSource) {
   userPropertyToUse = application.config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.dao.reflectionSaltSourceProperty
}
```