# How to Use Salt Generated in PHP in Grails Project

Tags: php, grails, spring-security, salt

I have a PHP application I'm converting to Grails. The PHP application used a salt-mechanism to encode the passwords of all its users.

When moving the salt and salted password into the (custom) user database in Grails, I am unable to log in while in my Grails application.

Of course, I'm using the [Spring Security Core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core), and I've added the salt to the User domain class as specified in [this tutorial](http://blog.swwomm.com/2010/06/grails-passwords-salted.html), which I found here: [Grails with Spring Security Plugin and Salted Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739296/grails-with-spring-security-plugin-and-salted-passwords)

After running through the tutorial, I am able to add a user and successfully log in with that user:

```
[BootStrap.groovy]:
new User( username:"user", email:"user@place.com", password:"password", enabled:true).save(flush: true)
```

(you might also notice the addition of email, which I added using [this tutorial](http://omarello.com/2010/09/grails-customize-authentication/))

But I am unable to login using any of the users that were transferred over from the PHP project. If it's any help, here's how their passwords were encoded:

```
$password = "password";
$salt = bin2hex( openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 32 ) );
$passwordSalted = hash( "sha256", $salt . $password );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Burt nailed it with his suggestion here: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-Core-plugin-and-multiple-salt-sources-tc3638236.html#a3646256

Basically, I already had my own salt provided from the tutorials I mentioned above, I just needed to combine it with the password using a custom password encoder.

```
public class CustomPasswordEncoder extends MessageDigestPasswordEncoder {

    public CustomPasswordEncoder() {
        super("SHA-256");
    }

    @Override
    protected String mergePasswordAndSalt(String password, Object salt, boolean strict) {
        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        if (salt == null || "".equals(salt)) {
            return password;
        }

        return salt + password;
    }
}
```